# Reading an external yml file in symfony1.4 with doctrine

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, yaml

I created one yml file

```
$loader = sfYaml::load('/pms/config/org.yml');
print_r($loader);
```

I have values in the yml file
but Its printing only the file name

```
/pms/config/org.yml
```

What could be the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens when the file does not exist. You are pointing to the root dir of you server.

Try something like this to point to the root dir of your project:

```
$loader = sfYaml::load( sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir') . '/config/org.yml' );
print_r($loader);
```